# CMake - defining and reusing header files in multiple sub targets

Tags: c++, cmake

I know, it is silly, but I have no idea how to fix this. I have an old C++ project made using VS and now I have to add CMake to it. The structure of the project is something like this:

```
PROJECT
|
- include
|       |
|       -folder
|             |-a.h
|             |
|             - folder
|                    b.h
|                ....
- lib1
|    |
|    CMakefiles.txt   
- lib2
|    |
|    CMakefiles.txt   
- main
|    |
|    CMakefiles.txt   
CMakefiles.txt
```

So, the include folder contains a lot of header files and those are organized in multiple subfolders. The project, beside the main (executable), defines a lot of shared libraries, some of them are dependent on other libraries. Each library folder has its own C++ header and source files. But almost each library includes headers from the include folder BUT just by the name (without path).

Basically I have two questions.

1. How should I organize the CMake for this folder structure?
2. How can I defining and reusing header files from the include folder for each library and the executable?

Comment: Are the headers in include header-only or implemented in one of the libraries? (or even multiple times)

Comment: The header files in the include folder are standalone headers. They contain only #define"s.

Answer (score 0):

1. In CMake projects its more common to have a root level `src/` directory. This is totally optional, though, the structure you've provided above is fine. In each library subdirectory, define a *target* using the [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) command. There you can add any source files you want to that target.
2. After adding the sources, the headers you have in your "include/" directory can be added to the target using the [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) function. Similarly, dependencies on other libraries in your project, or external libraries can be added using the [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command. An example of how that might look:

```
add_library(liba source1.cpp source2.cpp)

target_link_libraries(liba 
    libb
)

target_include_directories(liba
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
```

Keep in mind, a target only exists after it has been parsed. if liba depends on libb, you have to `add_subdirectory(libb)` first. External libraries will have to be added using either [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html), [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) or [fetch_content](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html)

Comment: I have already thested this target_include_directories but as I said, the headers are included only by name, not with path and name. So, in this way I have to enumerate all of them. If this is the case then it would be more elegant to define them once and reuse them where are needed.

Comment: At your root level CMakeLists.txt you can create a variable with the all of the sub-directory include paths and use that variable in your `target_include_directories` call.   My advice would be to update your source files to use the path, though.